# How to fix n+1 problem in Entity Framework Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, .net-core-2.0

I have this code

```
var query = DbContext.Set<WorkCertificate>()
                     .Include(u => u.WorkCertificateWorkers)
                     .Include(u => u.WorkCertificateGVSs)
                     .Where(filterExpression)
                     .Skip(filter.GetSkip()).Take(filter.GetTake());

var list = await query.ToListAsync();
```

`Typebuilder` of `WorkCertificate`. `WorkCertificate` is inherited from base class.

```
builder.HasMany(workCertificate => workCertificate.WorkCertificateWorkers)
    .WithOne(wcw => wcw.WorkCertificate)
    .HasForeignKey(wcw => wcw.WorkCertificateId);

builder.HasMany(workCertificate => workCertificate.WorkCertificateGVSs)
    .WithOne(wcw => wcw.WorkCertificate)
    .HasForeignKey(wcw => wcw.WorkCertificateId);
```

This code generates SQL. And you can see there are a lot of connections to DB and it causes large performance issues.

```
2020-04-08 16:27:52.0918|INFO|SimpleConsoleLogger|Executed DbCommand (59ms) [Parameters=[@__filter_Data_Id_0='?', @__p_2='?', @__p_1='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT "u"."id", "u"."allowed_to_copy", "u"."approval_state", "u"."certificate_category", "u"."xmin", "u"."created_date", "u"."creator_id", "u"."deleted", "u"."global_id", "u"."gvs_analysis_required", "u"."location_detail", "u"."modified_date", "u"."original_number", "u"."previous_approval_state", "u"."status_key", "u"."work_type", "u"."discriminator", "u"."is_expired_message_sent", "u"."isolation_certificate_required", "u"."linked_isolation_certificate_type", "u"."linked_lockout_certificate_type", "u"."lockout_certificate_required", "u"."shift", "u"."work_description_detail"
FROM "public"."certificate" AS "u"
WHERE ("u"."discriminator" = 'workCertificate') AND (("u"."deleted" = FALSE) AND ("u"."id" = @__filter_Data_Id_0))
ORDER BY "u"."id"
LIMIT @__p_2 OFFSET @__p_1
2020-04-08 16:27:52.2706|INFO|SimpleConsoleLogger|Executed DbCommand (80ms) [Parameters=[@__filter_Data_Id_0='?', @__p_2='?', @__p_1='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

SELECT "u.WorkCertificateWorkers"."id", "u.WorkCertificateWorkers"."additional_info", "u.WorkCertificateWorkers"."certificate_state", "u.WorkCertificateWorkers"."created_date", "u.WorkCertificateWorkers"."name", "u.WorkCertificateWorkers"."occupation", "u.WorkCertificateWorkers"."position_id", "u.WorkCertificateWorkers"."position_title", "u.WorkCertificateWorkers"."profile_id", "u.WorkCertificateWorkers"."qualification", "u.WorkCertificateWorkers"."work_certificate_id"
FROM "public"."work_certificate_workers" AS "u.WorkCertificateWorkers"
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT "u0"."id"
    FROM "public"."certificate" AS "u0"
    WHERE ("u0"."discriminator" = 'workCertificate') AND (("u0"."deleted" = FALSE) AND ("u0"."id" = @__filter_Data_Id_0))
    ORDER BY "u0"."id"
    LIMIT @__p_2 OFFSET @__p_1
) AS "t" ON "u.WorkCertificateWorkers"."work_certificate_id" = "t"."id"
ORDER BY "t"."id"
2020-04-08 16:27:52.3493|INFO|SimpleConsoleLogger|Executed DbCommand (50ms) [Parameters=[@__filter_Data_Id_0='?', @__p_2='?', @__p_1='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

SELECT "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"."id", "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"."checked_date", "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"."checked_place", "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"."comment", "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"."max_allowed_concentration", "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"."measuring_tool_number", "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"."measuring_tool_verification_date", "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"."name", "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"."position_title", "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"."result", "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"."substance", "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"."type_key", "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"."unit_of_measure", "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"."work_certificate_id"
FROM "public"."work_certificate_gvs" AS "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT "u1"."id"
    FROM "public"."certificate" AS "u1"
    WHERE ("u1"."discriminator" = 'workCertificate') AND (("u1"."deleted" = FALSE) AND ("u1"."id" = @__filter_Data_Id_0))
    ORDER BY "u1"."id"
    LIMIT @__p_2 OFFSET @__p_1
) AS "t0" ON "u.WorkCertificateGVSs"."work_certificate_id" = "t0"."id"
ORDER BY "t0"."id"
```

How can I get single SQL query instead of what I am getting now?

Comment: Write your own query?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: Thanks! It is a variant, but i would like to use linq.

Comment: Entity Framework is an 80 percent solution, always has been.  For that other 20 percent, you still need SQL.  While you might succeed in bending EF to your will using Linq, writing a custom query is probably a better solution that will give you more control over the outcome.

Comment: @SergiiVeremiyenko can you share your data models and filter expressions on the description of your question?

Comment: what @Nazim wrote, but I'll assume anyway - you may end up using join plus some lazy loading (if you have inverse properties for example etc)

Comment: Also "you do not". Ef Core 2.0 is so out of support it is not funny. 3.1 is the only supported version. Going back, 2.2 is the last 2.x line version (and that one is in some pieces better than 3.1). 2.0 is just "i do not upgrade, regardless how out of support something is". No sense in an answer. Upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by upgrading to ef core 3.1